# Read an Excel file without changing path under different operating systems in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a folder named test, and I want read its `test.xlsx` in Python under different computer environments .

```
#For Mac:
df = pd.read_excel('/Users/Steven/Desktop/test/test.xlsx')
#For Linux:
df = pd.read_excel('/Users/Users/Desktop/test/test.xlsx')
#For Windows:
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Desktop/test/test.xlsx')
```

I'm wondering is there any way to read this file in a general way without changing its file path. Please share any ideas that may help, thanks.

```
df = pd.read_excel('../test/test.xlsx')
```

Comment: `pathlib` is your friend, but without more context it's hard to give a definitive answer here

Comment: OS different....

Comment: I think you just want a _relative_ path. Your last code block is just posted with no context or questions/issues.

Comment: What does the project structure look like? Where is the Excel file in comparison to where you want to read the file?

Comment: I've writen a python script to analyze a bunch of excel data, say test.xlsx, and I transform this script from py to exe use Pyinstaller, i hope it can read test.xlsx in a folder test at any computer.

Comment: As  @aws_apprentice has mentioned, `pathlib` is the right tool.

Comment: @KenDekalb, could you please share more details? Thanks a lot.

Comment: os.path can also be an approach. Try my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, your idea is to read a file using the concept of relative path. To do so, we can use `os`. Let's suppose you have a parent folder, containing `/test/test.xlsx`. In this same parent folder, we can insert our python program (let's call it `my_pretty_program.py`):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

#gets your current directory
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)

#concatenates your current directory with your desired subdirectory
results = os.path.join(dirname, r'test\test.xlsx')

#reads the excel file in a dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(results, engine='python')

print(df)
```

And just like this you can do the trick. Remember to have the structure as:

```
Parent/
|-- my_pretty_program.py
|-- test/
|   |-- test.xlsx
```

Comment: I add an input to get directory path, it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't thank me! Just pay your honors to the Gods of Python!